# warning message "format not a string literal and no format arguments"

Tags: iphone

I am seeing this warning message "format not a string literal and no format arguments" but it is not showing in which line message is occurring. It is showing when I am debugging and running my application.  My file name is addaccount.m and it has some header file connected.

why this not showing line number?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a bad `NSLog` function call. Search for `NSLog` in your project and check if that's the thing.

Comment: Specifically this is a warning agains the uncontrolled format string vulnerability: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_vulnerabilities in other words: bad things may happen if you pass format specifiers as parameters. It's also likely that the number of format specifiers doesn't match the number of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If your pch file (common header) define a macro for nslog as below. You will get the line number.

```
#   define CustomLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

And replace NSLog with CustomLog